# Run a command multiple times with arguments given from standard input

Tags: unix

I remember seeing a unix command that would take lines from standard input and execute another command multiple times, with each line of input as the arguments.  For the life of me I can't remember what the command was, but the syntax was something like this:

```
ls | multirun -r% rm %
```

In this case `rm %` was the command to run multiple times, and `-r%` was an option than means replace `%` with the input line (I don't remember what the real option was either, I'm just using `-r` as an example).  The complete command would remove all files in the current by passing the name of each file in turn to `rm` (assuming, of course, that there are no directories in the current directory).  What is the real name of `multirun`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command is called 'xargs' :-) and you can run it as following

`ls | xargs echo I would love to rm -f the files`

Comment: Thanks!  The correct full command would be `ls | xargs -I% rm %`

Comment: no need for `%`s in there... I don't think... man 1 xargs should give you the exact flavour on your system

Comment: Yes you're right, `ls | xargs rm` would do in this case, I guess when I saw the command before it was more complicated and only part of the arguments were given from standard in, so the `-I%` was necessary

Comment: Hmm, after some experimentation it looks like `ls | xargs cmd` is equivalent to `cmd a b c` (where a-c are the files in the current directory), whereas `xargs -I% cmd %` is equivalent to `cmd a;cmd b;cmd c`.

Comment: `%x` is a bad choice here, since it is expanded by the shell ( at least korn and bash shells, IIRC). Tip: avoid `%`.

Comment: @wildplasser What does `%` expand to?  I use bash and I haven't had any problems with it

Comment: Job control. try `kill %1`.